# What is this construction site jacuuzi for

Tags: civil-engineering

There is a large drilling crane or something, which is connected by a giant hose to a skip full of water (central skip, blue). It looks like a jacuuzi but I suspect they are using it for something else.

[image: construction_site_jacuuzi]

Perhaps it is not a jacuuzi? What is it for if not?

Comment: You mean the blue containers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely to be  tanks for [drilling fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drilling_fluid) (aka 'mud').

This is a slurry of various substances, such as bentonite clay suspended in oil or water which serves various functions. In particular it provides cooling and lubrication for the drill head and helps to clear debris created by drilling.

When drilling into pressurised oil and gas wells it also provide a hydrostatic head which resists the well pressure.

Typically it will be pumped down the centre of the drill pipe and returns up through the gap between the drill pipe and the bore.

Drilling fluid is usually made up on site as needed by mixing dry ingredients with oil or water plus any additional additives.